# buffer size every increasing

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, flatbuffers

I'm using flatbuffers to process object streamings, should I call `FlatBufferBuilder::Clear` each time I finished to created an object? My code is like:

```
FlatBufferBuild fbb;
while (true) {
    Foo foo;
    RecvFooFromNetwork(&foo);
    FooObject = CreateFooObjectDirect(fbb, foo.x, foo.y, ...);
    SaveToDisk(fbb.GetBufferPointer(), fbb.GetSize());

    // <-- Should I call fbb.Clear() here?
}
```

I'm observing that `fbb.GetSize()` is for every increasing even though the size of `Foo` should be constant. Is that normal?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with C++ or C++11, so is off-topic with those tags.  It is really only relevant to usage of the flatbuffers library, which is not part of standard C++ at all.   You'll need to read documentation from the originator of the library (i.e. google).

Comment: @Peter he's using the library in C++, thus problems in using the library may relate to C++ semantics, and thus using this tag is totally valid. I agree that in this case wether to "Clear" an object or not is almost language agnostic, but in the general case your idea that the C++ tag is reserved for code that only uses standard libraries is unpractical, especially for a library like FlatBuffers that leans heavily on how C++ deals with memory.

Comment: @Aardappel - In the general case, if you want to know how to use a library (or a function/class in that library) refer to documentation of that library.   That has nothing to do with C++ semantics, and everything to so with the logic implemented by that library.   The only C++ developers who will be able to help with this problem will be those who know about flatbuffers.  Those people will be quite a small minority of C++ developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you answered your own question, you need to either call `Clear()` (most efficient) or move the declaration of `fbb` inside the loop. When you finish a buffer it stays in the builder. There could probably be an assert for creating more data after you call `Finish()`, maybe open an issue on github?

Comment: In the flatbuffers sample code it never calls `Clear()`, so i was not sure whether it's right to call it in this case.

Comment: The sample code also doesn't create multiple buffers using the same `FlatBufferBuilder`

Comment: It is creating buffers in a loop.